# Why Worpdress doesn't create table in database?

Tags: plugin-development, database

Primarily this is the only code in my main plugin page. It should create table in the database while I am activating it. But, it is not working at all. Plugin activating successfully. Please, help me to figure this out.

```
/*
* Plugin Name: Titan Video Plugin
* Description: A simple and my first plugin, just for testing.
* Author: Allen Titan.
* Version: 0.1.
* License: GPL3
*/

if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'titan_vedio_table' );

function titan_vedio_table() {
global $wpdb;
global $titan_db_version;

$table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."titanvedio";

$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . "(
    id BIGINT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    videoname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    video-des VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
);";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );

add_option( 'titan_db_version', $titan_db_version );
}
```

Comment: where can i buy a worpdress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is fairly temperamental syntax, not sure if it will make a difference but try adding the missing space before ( and removing ; from the end:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
    id BIGINT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
    videoname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    video-des VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id)
)";
```

The other thing I wonder if hyphens are allowed ie. `video-des`, since most table names use `_` it made me think... this answer seems to suggest is it fine *only if it is enclosed with the correct quotes* ie. backticks not single quotes - so you may want to change it anyway to avoid future problems:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168644/can-a-table-field-contain-a-hyphen

(although it is referring to table names not column key names so not totally sure on this.)

In any case you can check the return value of `dbDelta` it may give you a better idea. Since you can't probably see the result during activation due to redirects, I'd write it to a file:

```
$result = dbDelta($sql);
ob_start(); print_r($result); 
file_put_contents(get_template_directory().'/dbdebug.txt',ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: I figured it out. The hyphen was the problem there. And It has worked fine. Thanks @majick for your help.

Comment: sweet so it was that after all, glad it worked out